# How to add share points CAML query in rest service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

This is my SharePoint CAML query condition

```
<View>
     <Query>
     <Where>
     <Geq>
       <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
         <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>2016-04-28T06:04:28.183Z</Value>
     </Geq>
    </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

I tried duplicating this using a REST url, but I am getting the message

> "The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression".

Can someone guide me to correct my URL

```
http://mySite//_api/lists/getbytitle('test')/items?$filter=EventDate gt datetime'2016-04-04T00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write caml query in data section of ajax call and POST it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/getitems",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
    query : {
      __metadata: {
        type: "SP.CamlQuery" 
      },
      ViewXml: 'Your CAML Query'
    }
  }),
    success: function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Updates:

Date comparison syntax is bit different . Also  "?" after items was missing.  Here is the updated URL ==> `http://mysite/_api/lists/getbytitle('test')/items?$filter=EventDate gt datetime'2016-04-04T00:00:00'`.

Comment: Hi Vijay ata, Thanks for the response. I need to form a Rest URl based on my camel query.

Comment: Date comparison syntax is bit different . Also  "?" after items was missing.  Here is the updated URL ==> `http://mysite/_api/lists/getbytitle('test')/items?$filter=EventDate gt datetime'2016-04-04T00:00:00'`.

Comment: Hi i tried with updated URL but still am getting the same message.